# Display image in web use file .php

Tags: php, android

i am a newbie android programmer, i not good at website design. However, i have a project send image from android to website, image is sent from android to website ok fine when i use this script

```
<?php
    $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
     $binary=base64_decode($base);
    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
    $file = fopen('uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb');
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);
    echo 'Image upload complete!!, Please check your php file directory……';
?>
```

and my picture located [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDu3S.png).

but now i would like to show image in web page(in my website nns12151069.esy.es), what should i write more in script .php

Comment: `<img src="uploaded_image.jpg">`? just because that image was uploaded from something else doesn't make it magically different than any other image on your server. you'd access it like any other image.

Comment: i was add your line to my script, like this <?php
    $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
     $binary=base64_decode($base);
    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
    $file = fopen('uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb');
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);
 echo "<img src= 'uploaded_image.jpg' width='300' height='300'/> ";
?>                                                                                                              but nothing happen. In my website ,it still not display my picture

Answer (score 0):

Please lookup the file upload with php http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

another hand you can call directly your image from uploaded path